# Могу ли я обратится к объекту по objectName()?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qss, qlayout, objectname

Могу ли я обратится к объекту через его `objectName()`, ведь это очень полезно, особенно когда я использую:

```
for x in range(6):
    label = QLabel()
    label.setObjectName('label_{}'.format(x))
label.findChild('label_1').setStyleSheet('background:green;')
```

---

Раньше я для этого использовал массив:

```
arr = []

for x in range(6):
    label = QLabel()
    arr.append(label)
arr[1].setStyleSheet('background:green;')
```

Но думаю с точки зрения оптимизаций кода лучше все же это делать через `objectName()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys 
from PyQt5.Qt import *

class Demo(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        lay = QGridLayout(self)

        for x in range(6):
            label = QLabel(f'Label_{x}')
            label.setObjectName('label_{}'.format(x))
            lay.addWidget(label)

#        label.findChild('label_1').setStyleSheet('background:green;')
        self.setStyleSheet('#label_1 {background: green; color: #fff}')


if __name__== "__main__":
    mi_aplicacion= QApplication(sys.argv)
    mi_app = Demo()
    mi_app.show()
    sys.exit(mi_aplicacion.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**

> Мне нужно не только `setStyleSheet` но и другие операций `connect()`, `isChecked()` и многие другие.

---

Вы можете использовать `setattr()` / `getattr()`
для динамического создания переменных, используя строку, как показано ниже:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *

class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        flay = QFormLayout(self)
        self.texts = [["name", "какое-то имя"], 
                      ["address", "какой-то адрес"], 
                      ["phone", "какой-то телефон"]]

        for i, text in enumerate(self.texts):
            label = QLabel(text[0]+": ")
            label.setFixedSize(120, 30)
            self.lineEdit = QLineEdit()
            flay.addRow(label, self.lineEdit)

            # Атрибут класса создается с помощью setattr()        
            setattr(self, "lineEdit_{}".format(i+1), self.lineEdit)                 # !!!

        flay.addRow(QPushButton("Click me", clicked=self.create_txt)) 

        # использование так:
        for i, _ in enumerate(self.texts):
            obj = getattr(self, "lineEdit_{}".format(i+1))                          # !!!         
            obj.setText(self.texts[i][1])
            obj.editingFinished.connect(lambda obj=obj: self.editing_finished(obj)) # !!!
            obj.textChanged.connect(lambda text, obj=obj: obj.setStyleSheet(''))    # !!!

    def create_txt(self):
        for i, _ in enumerate(self.texts):
            obj = getattr(self, "lineEdit_{}".format(i+1))                          # !!!
            print(f"{obj.text()}")    

    def editing_finished(self, obj):
        print(obj.text())

        # использовать можно и так:
        self.lineEdit_1.setStyleSheet('')
        self.lineEdit_2.setStyleSheet('')
        self.lineEdit_3.setStyleSheet('')

        obj.setStyleSheet('background: green; color: #fff')                         # !!!


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Example()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Мне нужно не только setStyleSheet но и другие операций pressed.connect()  isChecked() и многие другие.